# Small question about contravariant functors

Tags: category-theory, functors, ring-homomorphism

I am new to Category Theory and it was recommended to me to start my understanding of basic concepts by reading $\textit{Basic Category Theory}$ by Tom Leinster.

But I am finding myself struggling a bit with the notion of $\textit{Contravariant Functor}$. In one of his many examples, namely $\textit{Example 1.2.11}$, it is meant to show that, given a topological space $X$ and $C(X)$, the ring of real-valued functions at X, $C$ corresponds to a contravariant functor from $\textbf{Top}$ to $\textbf{Ring}$.

However, the part that I am not understanding is why when we define a function
$$
f:X \rightarrow Y
$$
we induce a ring homomorphism
$$
C(f):C(Y)\rightarrow C(X)
$$
More particularly, I wish someone could give me some hints as to why $C(f)$ goes in the opposite direction from $f$.

Any help is really appreciated! Thank you in advance, for taking your time to read my question.

Comment: Covariant goes in the "same" direction, and Contravariant in the opposite direction - by definition of these words for functors - see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CovariantFunctor.html) and [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContravariantFunctor.html).

Comment: If we have a continuous real valued function on Y and a continuous function from X to Y, we can precompose by the latter and get a continuous real valued function on X. The functor reverses the direction of the arrows because it is mapping morphisms in Top to the operation of precomposition by that morphism on the continuous real valued functions of the codomain.

Comment: sorry, the real valued functions, not necessarily continuous, though the point is the same

Comment: Tom Leinster's book is terrific, but I suspect it is a bit tougher going than he perhaps intends. So check out https://www.logicmatters.net/categories/ for links to a LOT of freely available resources at varying levels -- it might be a good plan to find one or two others that work for you to read in parallel to _Basic Category Theory_.

Answer (score 1):

Given topological spaces $X, Y$ and a continuous function $f : X \to Y$, given any real-valued function $\phi : Y \to \mathbb{R}$ we can produce a function $X \to \mathbb{R}$ by composing:

$$X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{\phi} \mathbb{R}$$

That is, we get the real valued function sending $x \in X$ to $\phi (f (x)) \in \mathbb{R}$.

This is an example of a much more general phenomenon:

> Precomposing flips the direction of arrows, while postcomposing keeps it as it is

Another instance of this fact can be seen when you consider the following setup: fix any category $\mathcal{C}$ and an object $c : \mathcal{C}$ in it. We can cook up a functor $\mathbf{Y}_c : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ into the category of sets by defining

$$\mathbf{Y}_c(a) := \mathbf{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}[a, c]$$

using the hom-sets. Now, this functor is *contravariant* just as the one you described, and for the same exact reason: given a morphism $f : a \to a^\prime$ in $\mathcal{C}$, we want to produce a function between the hom-sets:

$$\mathbf{Y}_c(a^\prime) = \mathbf{Hom}_\mathcal{C}[a^\prime, c] \xrightarrow{f^*} \mathbf{Hom}_\mathcal{C}[a, c] = \mathbf{Y}_c(a)$$

The function $f^*$ is given in the same way: given $\phi : a^\prime \to c$, we produce

$$a \xrightarrow{f} a^\prime \xrightarrow{\phi} c$$

The functor $\mathbf{Y}_c$ is extremely important, by the way: it's called the **Yoneda embedding** of $c : \mathcal{C}$.

As you'll see later on, the assignment $c \mapsto \mathbf{Y}_c$ is actually a (covariant) functor itself (from $\mathcal{C}$ to the category of contravariant functors $\mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ into the category of sets). This functor is the main player of a very important result in category theory: the **Yoneda lemma**.